# What Azure DevOps Server / Team Foundation Server version first introduced support for Git LFS

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm trying to figure out which version of Team Foundation Server (TFS) / Azure DevOps Server first introduced support for Git Large File Storage (LFS). I know that it is currently supported on Azure DevOps **Service** (not server) and that it is free there and blablabla. But nowhere in the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes) of TFS / Azure DevOps Server / Azure DevOps Service do I find any mention of when it was introduced.

The [documentation of the feature itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-large-files) just mentions the following:

> If you use a version of LFS below 2.4.0 with Azure DevOps Server or TFS, there's an extra setup step required to authenticate using NTLM instead of Kerberos

This implies that even TFS supported Git LFS already. However, there is no mention of the actual version.

If that question cannot be answered, the next best question I have is whether Git LFS is supported on Azure DevOps Server 2019 (Dev17.M153.5). Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which version of Team Foundation Server (TFS) / Azure DevOps Server first introduced support for Git Large File Storage (LFS).

From looking at the [Announcing Git-LFS on all VSO Git repos](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-git-lfs-on-all-vso-git-repos/),

> Coming soon, Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 1 will also support Git-LFS.

I think Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 1 starts supporting for Git LFS.

Hope it can help.